# Replacing DrawerLayout's RelativeLayout with a Fragment's layout doesn't work but no error is shown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

When the user clicks on the menu item Posts, it must replace the activity's layout with the started fragment's layout.

The activity's layout (set with `setContentView`) is:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="@style/Album.MatchParent"
        android:id="@+id/RL"
        android:background="@color/albumPageLight">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            style="@style/Album.AppBar.General">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                style="@style/Album.Toolbar.Light" />

            <include layout="@layout/album_content_album"/>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view_log_out" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The aim is to replace the `RelativeLayout` with the fragment's layout. To do that, I use the following code:

```
if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_item_posts_page) {
    fragment_transaction.replace(R.id.RL, new PostsFragment(), PostsFragment.class.getSimpleName());
    if (saved_state != null && !saved_state.equals(PostsFragment.class.getSimpleName())) {
        fragment_transaction.addToBackStack(PostsFragment.class.getSimpleName());
    }
    fragment_transaction.commit();
}
```

Note that the `RL` is correctly the ID of the `RelativeLayout`.

The `PostsFragment`'s layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar_no_sql_request"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TESTETSETE"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/progressBar_no_sql_request"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/posts_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar_no_sql_request" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Problem: when I click on the menu item Posts, no error is shown but no layout is replaced at all. **Is it due to something I've forgotten in the code I've given above?**

Comment: replace method will not replace relative layout with fragment.
according to docs
`containerViewId int: Identifier of the container whose fragment(s) are to be replaced.`

Comment: Well this is the good container I should use. So why isn't it working?

Comment: `FragmentTransaction`s will not remove or replace any `View`s that do not belong to a `Fragment`. Your transaction is just adding the `Fragment`'s `View` to what's already in the `RelativeLayout`. If you want those `View`s removed/replaced, put them into a separate layout for their own `Fragment` class that you load in code at startup. Your subsequent transactions will then behave as you're expecting.

Comment: @MikeM. why don't you create an answer? I'd be happy to upvote it!

Comment: Oh, it's cool. :-) This is a rather common issue, so I'll just mark this as a duplicate of another question with the same problem. For the sake of full disclosure, I do mention a couple of other options in my answer on that question that might be usable for your setup. I'm always loath to suggest those other options, though, because they're kinda hacky, and they usually end up causing further problems down the line. Anyhoo, thank you for the offer. I really appreciate it. Glad you got it squared away. Cheers!